# Suppose $0<a<1$. Show $\{a^n\}$decreasing, converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $0<a<1$.

Show $\{a^n\}$ decreasing sequence.

I am attempting to use monotone strictly increasing where,

Want to show, $a^n > a^{n+1}$

define $a = 1/2$ then $a^2 = 1/4$. Can I show this abstractly?

Show $\{a^n\}$ converges.

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N = 1/a \epsilon$  s.t. $n>N$, Then

$|a^n - L| \leq 1/an - L < 1/aN = \epsilon$ does this need more explanation?

Comment: You can use $a^{n+1} = a^n a < a^n 1$, if you showed $a^n >0$ already.

Comment: @JohnMa This is a bit random but are you related to Michael Ma?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee : Um.... Not really ^^. My name is really John Ma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs way more explanation. If you want to check convergence formally, you need to show
$$∀ε > 0~∃ N ∈ ℕ~∀n > N~\lvert a^n \rvert < ε,$$
since the limit of $(a^n)_n$ for $\lvert a \rvert < 1$ is always zero as you can tell by inspecting some well-known examples (so set $L = 0$ in your formulation).

You wrote “$\lvert a^n - L\rvert ≤ 1/an - L$”. Do you mean “$\frac 1 {an}$” or “$\frac 1 a n$”? Probably the former. But how did you conclude that? This is not clear at all.

The usual way of showing the convergence of the [geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) is a two-step process:

- Show that a sequence $(a_n)_n$ of positive real numbers converges to zero if and only if its reciprocal sequence $(1/a_n)_n$ *increases without bounds*, i. e.
  $$∀κ > 0~∃N∈ℕ~∀n > N~a_n > κ.$$
- Show that for $b > 1$, $(b^n)_n$ increases without bounds by invoking [Bernoulli’s Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality).

For the decreasing part: See John Ma’s comment (use $a^n > 0$ and $a < 1$ to conclude $a^n·a < a^n·1$ using the order axioms on $ℝ$).